# Reading columns dynamically from Excel in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I have an excel file with key columns and also 365 columns with dates as header in different columns for whole year,  My requirement is to read key columns and also the date column which equals to current day only.

For example when Power Automate workflow runs on  10th Jan, it should read the date under the column - 10th Jan only . Not other columns like 9th or 11th Jan. Next day it should read 11th Jan and so on.

Is it possible to automate such scenarios in power automate. How can I enable power automate flow to read different columns in excel

Thanks
Siva.

I tried all the options to choose dynamic columns, couldn't find any option in power automate to do it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Answer (score 1):

you can use the "Parse JSON" action to parse the response from the "List Rows Present in a Table" action and then access the column value based on its order number using the "Compose" action. Here's a revised approach:

```
Add the "List Rows Present in a Table" action from the Excel Online (Business) connector to your flow.

Specify the Excel file and table name in the action configuration.

Add a "Parse JSON" action from the Data Operations connector.

In the "Content" field of the "Parse JSON" action, select the output from the "List Rows Present in a Table" action.

In the "Schema" field of the "Parse JSON" action, provide a sample response from the "List Rows Present in a Table" action. You can run the flow with a sample Excel table to generate the response schema automatically.

After the "Parse JSON" action, add a "Compose" action.

In the "Inputs" field of the "Compose" action, use the following expression to retrieve the column value by order number.
```

e.g.

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['value'][0][body('Parse_JSON')?['$connections']['shared_excelonlinebusiness']['outputs']['tableRowsSchema']['items'][<OrderNumber>]['propertyId']]
```